# grab the web html source file with java

Tags: java, url, web, html

I'm trying to use java to open a URL and get the html source and do some analyses. I expect it to work like a browser, with which you can load the page and right-click to look at the html source. I had the following code, which is a pretty standard way I think.

```
public class getWeb {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private static final String url = "http://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/top/united-states/games/action/?device=iphone&date=2014-05-08";
    private static final String url_alt = "http://www.mkyong.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            URL appannie = new URL(url_alt);
            URLConnection page = appannie.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                     page.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                a.append(inputLine);
            in.close();

            System.out.println(a.toString());
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that url does not work, it just returns me a status code of 503, which means it's not available. But I can definitely open that page in a browser and see the html code, and I can also get the html if I use url_alt instead.

I'm not very familiar with the web server, I don't why I cannot just get the html source of all kinds of URLs, like using a browser. I also tried some other apis such as jsoup and apache's httpclient, but the problem is the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried your code and worked like charm. maybe sth not related to code, i don't know like firewall stuff or sth?

Comment: Same, your code works for me.

Comment: you mean you can get the html from the first url? My another friend tried it and also got 503...